# multiple values for a key PHP

Tags: php, content-management-system

New to PHP so forgive me if I don't know the nomenclature. Below I set keys to correspond with fields in our CMS along with conditions for pulling results based on those keys.

```
if (!empty($query->where[1])) {
    foreach ($query->where[1]['conditions'] as $key => $value) {
      if (strstr($query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['field'], 'field_data_field_program_type.field_program_type_value')) {
        $query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['field'] = '(field_data_field_program_type.field_program_type_value = :program_type_value AND field_data_field_project_type.field_project_type_value = :activity_project_type)'
            . ' OR field_data_field_project_type.field_project_type_value = :tl_project_type';
        $query->where[1]['conditions'][$key]['value'] = array(
          ':program_type_value' => 'Calendar',
          ':activity_project_type' => ACTIVITY_PROJECT_TYPE,
          ':tl_project_type' => TL_PROJECT_TYPE,
        );
```

However, now I need an additional value (let's call it 'Test') assigned to 'program_type_value' key, because I need to pull results containing both 'Calendar' and 'Test' . I have tried a few things but can't get anything to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
':program_type_value' => array('Calendar','Test')
```

or, in PHP 5.4+

```
':program_type_value' => ['Calendar','Test']
```